# Magento 2: Restrict customer to use 1 coupon code

Tags: magento2, coupon

I have multiple coupon codes in my store. The customer should not be able to use a coupon if he/she has already used a coupon before? Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: I mean from past orders.

Comment: use Uses per Customer to 1

Comment: Please check my updated answer and accept answer if it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Marketing -> Cart Price Rule -> Select specific rule -> Select specific coupon code and then set value in Uses per coupon & Uses per Customer.

- **Uses per Coupon:** Set the number of times the Coupon can be used.
- **Uses per Customer:** Set the number of times the same client uses the
  Coupon.

Comment: hi Rohan, thank you so much for your quick answer. I'm not very clear with my objective in my question above so I'm adding a situation here. If I have SUPERDISCOUNT50 and ULTRADISCOUNT100, once the customer has used the SUPERDISCOUNT50 in the past, he or she can no longer use the SUPERDISCOUNT50 and ULTRADISCOUNT100 in the future. Maybe if I can put them into group for flexibility, that would be great.